# What's the (official) term for a type's type?

Tags: c#, types, metadata, naming, roslyn

I'm writing an application using Roslyn to syntactically and semantically analyse C# source code. For each type defined in the source code being analysed, I would like to store whether it's a reference type (a class), a value type (a struct) or an interface.

What's the appropriate/official term for a type's type?

Example:

```
class A
{
    //This type's type (A's type) is 'class' (i.e. a reference type).
}
```

Comment: Haskell calls this type of thing "kind". Maybe it's similar in .NET.

Comment: Not sure if there's an official term for the collection which includes Class, Interface, Enum, Type, etc.  I'd call them structures but would put in a footnote/glossary entry to define my use of that term throughout the context of the document.

Comment: this question demands Jon Skeet :)!

Comment: since we're talking about syntax id say it's a `keyword`, and the type of the keyword is `structural`. `int` would be `data type` and `partial` => `contextual`. 
@BehnamEsmaili I thought about him as I was reading the question.. :D

Comment: @Alechandro I called it 'syntactically' because my application currently only uses the syntax analysis part of Roslyn, but I suppose at this point it's actually more semantic analysis...

Comment: @lesderid Ah I see... It's a very interesting question though. Maybe there is no official term, hence no official answer. I'd call them JuckNorris until you get the right word for it. Or JonSkeet... maybe even better  =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to know the official name, look into the official source: the C# language specification. Quoting from there (§1.3 Types and variables; emphasis mine):

> There are two **kinds of types** in C#: value types and reference types. […]
>
> C#’s value types are further divided into simple types, enum types, struct types, and nullable types, and C#’s reference types are further divided into class types, interface types, array types, and delegate types.

Then there is a table that describes those groups of types as **category**, and also this quote:

> Five of C#’s **categories of types** are user-definable: class types, struct types, interface types, enum types, and delegate types.

Although later (in §4 Types):

> The types of the C# language are divided into two main **categories**: Value types and reference types.

To sum up, the specification calls them categories of types, although its usage of that term is not very consistent.

Comment: Great answer! I personally would use 'kind' when talking about one type and 'category' when talking about a group of types (i.e. a category of types is a group of types of the same kind).

Answer (score 3):

In type theory, the type of a type is usually called its *kind*. That primarily describes the form of parameterisation of a type, although it can be used for other classifications, too. But I'm not sure whether it applies naturally to the sort of classification you are referring to here. It seems that C# does not have an "official" term for that either.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen us use "kind" in the Roslyn source code, as in "there are 5 possible kinds of types that can be declared". However I don't think there is an officially defined term for this. I'd use "kind of type" or "kind".